# Form em Django com mais de um Model

Tags: python, django, formulário

Sou novato na programação e estou tentando fazer um formulário utilizando mais de um Model em Django.
Eu até consegui fazer listar os fields do forms.py, mas quando solicito pra salvar ele grava apenas os dados do primeiro model.
O erro que dá é "NOT NULL constraint failed: Geral_usuario.colaboradorId_id", que acredito que seja por não conseguir recuperar o id do colaborador que acabou de ser cadastrado.
Como eu poderia estar solucionando isso?

Refiz um "mini-código" para dar uma ideia de como estou fazendo.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Colaborador(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField()

class Usuario(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(unique=True)
    senha = models.CharField()
    colaboradorId = models.OneToOneField('Colaborador', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Email(Contato):
    email = models.CharField()
    colaboradorId = models.ForeignKey('Colaborador', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

forms.py:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from .models import Colaborador, Usuario, Email

class FormUsuario(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Usuario
        fields = ['user', 'senha']

class FormColaborador(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Colaborador
        fields = ['nome']

class FormEmail(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Colaborador
        fields = ['nome']
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import FormUsuario, FormColaborador, FormEmail

def Cadastro(request):
    data = {}

    if request.method == "POST":
        data['colaborador'] = FormColaborador(request.POST, None)
        data['usuario'] = FormUsuario(request.POST, None)
        data['email'] = FormEmail(request.POST, None)

        if data['colaborador'].is_valid():
            colaborador = data['colaborador'].save(commit=False)
            id = colaborador.id
            if data['usuario'].is_valid():
                usuario = data['usuario']
                usuario.colaboradorId = id
                if data['email'].is_valid():
                    email = data['email']
                    email.colaboradorId = id
                    colaborador.save()
                    usuario.save()
                    email.save()
                    return redirect('lista')
    else:
        data['colaborador'] = FormColaborador()
        data['usuario'] = FormUsuario()
        data['email'] = FormEmail()

    return render(request, 'cadastro.html', data)
```

cadastro.html:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ colaborador.as_p }}
    {{ usuario.as_p }}
    {{ email.as_p }}
    <button class="btn btn-success">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

O motivo do erro é que você está "salvando" o colaborador com `commit=False`, assim:

```
colaborador = data['colaborador'].save(commit=False)
```

O `commit=False` faz com que o objeto não seja persistido no banco de dados, o que por sua vez faz com que ele **não tenha um id**. Então por isso quando você tenta atribuir o `contribuidor.id` depois, o `id` na realidade vai ser `None`, o que causará o erro de constraint.

Então pra resolver, basta remover o commit:

```
colaborador = data['colaborador'].save()
```